# Cross Azure AD resources

Tags: azure

If there are 2 companies with different domains, one is companyA and the other is companyB, they both have an Azure AD, Azure AD B2C and backend mobile application (backendA and backendB).

There are existing front-end mobile App mobileA which can access backendA after Azure AD B2C authentication of companyA and mobileB access backendB after Azure AD B2C authentication of companyB.

For my case, I want mobileA call the api of **backendB** after authentication of Azure AD B2C of companyA. But after getting the token from companyA, how backendB check the token is valid?

Thanks!
lihoma

Answer (score 0):

You can register backendB in companyA's tenant as an app.
The mobileA app can acquire a token for backendB from its own tenant.
Then backendB will need to add support for companyA's tokens in addition to supporting companyB's tokens.

Comment: Do you have any document can reference? Thanks!